# how to share text on facebook Through android app which is login through facebook Parse

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-sharer

I am working on adding share on facebook functionality to my app. I have the new version of parse sdk with facebook .

I can't seem to find information on how to use parse's fb sdk to implement share.

I have facebook session open into my app but don't understand how to post text or share text on facebook in android.

please give me any suggestions .

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got ans :)

here is solution :

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

WebDialog feedDialog = (
    new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        params))
    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
            FacebookException error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // When the story is posted, echo the success
                // and the post Id.
                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                if (postId != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // User clicked the Cancel button
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                // User clicked the "x" button
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Publish cancelled", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Generic, ex: network error
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Error posting story", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    })
    .build();
feedDialog.show();
```